# I want to print the list that is declared from Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
string Listprinted = Console.ReadLine(); //fiora

            string aatroxS = "Man Sofia 16";
            List<string> aatrox = aatroxS.Split(" ").ToList();

            string fioraS = "Woman Varna 15";
            List<string> fiora = fioraS.Split(" ").ToList(); //this should be printed with the input "fiora"

            string gwenS = "Woman Gabrovo 17";
            List<string> gwen = gwenS.Split(" ").ToList();

            //Console.WriteLine(Listprinted.List);
```

What I have in the input is the string `fiora` that is declared by the user using the `Console.ReadLine()`. I also have the list called `fiora`. Aside from 3 `else if` statements, is there any way I can print the list with the same name as the input that is declared in the string `Listprinted` - in the current example - `fiora`? If the input is aatrox the list aatrox should be printed, if the input is gwen, the list gwen should be printed, if the input is fiora, the list fiora should be printed.The problem is i currently have 160 of these names that should be printed when a user types the name of the list so an `if else` statement wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: so this: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", fiora));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) with the list name as the key and the list as value. Than you can access the lists by the user input. Finaly to display the lists content, you can use the function `string.Join()` that will concat the list values with a given delimiter.

Example:

```cs
// Get list name from user input
string Listprinted = Console.ReadLine();

// Declare lists
Dictionary<string, List<string>> lists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
lists.Add("aatrox", new List<string>() { "Man", "Sofia", "16" });
lists.Add("fiora", new List<string>() { "Woman", "Varna", "15" });
lists.Add("gwen", new List<string>() { "woman", "Gabrovo", "17" });

// Print list
if (lists.ContainsKey(Listprinted)) {
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", lists[Listprinted]));
}

// Output: Woman, Varna, 15
```

Comment: this solution is great, but I have another question not related to the title. What if I want to print the gender of  `aatrox`, that being `Man` (element 0) here? I haven't really used lists inside a dictionary too much...

Comment: In a dictionary an item (in your case a list) is accessd by a key. So `lists["aatrox"]` will return your `List<string>` object: `List<string> aatrox = lists["aatrox"]'`.  Than you can work with that list and you can get the first element by `aatrox[0]` afterwards. Or, a shorter way to access the first element would be `lists["aatrox"][0]`.

Maybe this article is helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections